# Build Numpy with Eigen instead of ATLAS or OpenBlas?

Tags: python, numpy, eigen

since [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) looks very promising ([Benchmark](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Benchmark)) I wonder if it was possible to compile numpy with the Eigen library, as it is possible to build numpy with ATLAS or with OpenBlas (or with intel-mkl). I was trying to play a little bit in the config but I guess this is beyond my reach.
[image: Benchmark from different linear algebra cores, Higher = better]

Comment: I question that benchmark.  Eigen only uses SSE while MKL uses AVX.  MKL is the best choice of GEMM.

Answer (score 2):

From the eigen sources, you can build a BLAS interface library and then link Numpy to it. For the first part:

```
make build-eigen
cd build-eigen
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release path/to/eigen
make blas lapack
```

This gives you a BLAS and LAPACK libraries with both static and shared versions. Then simply link Numpy to, e.g., libeigen_blas_static.a instead of ATLAS.

Also, note that this benchmark is quite old, and done on a single SSE processor. The figure might be different with, e.g., AVX.